Do data support that the probability of color blindness in girls equals the square of that in boys?
I wish to verify a potential solution for the following exercise:

We have only worked with the Wald statistic and the Log-ratio statistic for testing. These can be found in the book we are working with as:
$$W_n = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(OBS_j - EXP_j)^2}{EXP_j}=\displaystyle\sum_{j} R_j^2$$
where
$$R_j = \frac{OBS_j - EXP_j}{\sqrt{EXP_j}}$$
and the Log-ratio statistic is given by:
$$\Lambda_n=2\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k OBS_j log(\frac{OBS_j}{EXP_j})$$
hvor $OBS_j = Y_j$, $EXP_j = n\cdot \pi_j(\hat{\beta})$.
My idea with the exercise was that I need to set up a
$$H_0 : \pi_{boy} = \mu$$
and an additional null hypothesis would be:
$$H_1 : \pi_{girl} = \pi_{boy}^2$$
I then thought that
$$\hat{\pi_{boy}}=\frac{\text{# Colorblind boys}}{\text{# Total number of boys}}$$
One can use this MLE to work further on the task, where one can now determine $EXP_j{girl}$ and from there calculate the LogRatio statistic and Wald statistic.
I have written the following code to test the additional null hypothesis:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2

data = np.array([[725,40],[8324,9032]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Boy','Girls'], index=['Colorblind','Normal'])

# Tilføjer ("addmargins()")
    # 1. Summen af hver kolonne
    # 2. Summen af hver række
df.loc['Total - Columns'] = df.sum(axis=0)
df['Total - Rows'] = df.sum(axis=1)

# Bruger pi_MLE_dreng (s.180)
pi_boy = df.loc['Colorblind','Boy']/df.loc['Total - Columns','Boy'] 
pi_girls= pi_boy**2

print(f"MLE probability for boy: {pi_boy}\nH_0 MLE proability for girls: {pi_girls}\n")

# Bestem EXP_j_girls
df['EXP_hypo_girls'] = pi_girls*df['Total - Rows']
# Bestem residualer:
df['Residual_hypo_girls'] = [(i-j)/(np.sqrt(j)) for i,j in zip(df['Girls'],df['EXP_hypo_girls'])]

print(df)

# Bestem wald-statistikken:
wald_girls = df.iloc[0,4]**2+df.iloc[1,4]**2

print(f"\nWald-statistic: {wald_girls}\n")

# H_0 : Test om mu_girls= mu_boy^2
p_værdi = 1-chi2.cdf(wald_girls,1)

print(f"P-value for wald-statistic er: {p_værdi}")




I'm a little concerned with the magnitude of the Wald statistic. Also, note how large the residuals are.
I hope some of you will take a look at this solution and give me some advice, because i don't think it's correct.

Just 2 terminology comments: Your $W_n$ is not the Wald test statistic, but a score test statistic (in this case, the Pearson's $\chi^2$); and what you called LogRatio is generally known as (log) likelihood ratio test statistic (aka $G^2$ statistic in this particular case).

One problem is with your $\hat{\pi}_{\text{boy}}$: it did not consider the constraint imposed by $H_0: {\pi}_{\text{boy}}^2={\pi}_{\text{girl}}$. It's only an MLE under $H_0 \cup H_0^C$, which is less efficient, if $H_0$ is true.

For your score test statistic (the one you called "Wald"), you definitely need to impose the constraint when calculating the expected frequencies.
For a truly Wald test statistic, using your $\hat{\pi}$ is fairly common.

However, Wald test in contingency tables is generally not commonly used.


For likelihood ratio test, you actually need both versions of estimate of $\pi_{\text{boy}}$.


Edit 1: A simplified example using the likelihood ratio test
For simplicity, I will assume a two-independent binomial model, by conditioning on both the total number of boys ($n_1$) and the total number of girls ($n_2$). This model has minimal assumptions made and is probably fairly generally applicable. Alternative models might be contrived for this data, depending on how the sampling was performed and what assumptions one might impose (e.g., do we assume a $1:1$ sex ratio?) But I will not deal with those subtleties and focus on the basic idea of LRT for now.
Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be the colorblind proportions in the boys and girls population, respectively. And let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the corresponding colorblind case count in the sample.
Under an unconstrained model,
$$
X_1\sim\text{Binom}(n_1,\pi_1)\text{ independent of }X_2\sim\text{Binom}(n_2,\pi_2).
$$The unconstrained estimates are just the sample proportions.
Under constraint $H_0: \pi_1^2=\pi_2$, we have
$$
X_1\sim\text{Binom}(n_1,\pi_1)\text{ independent of }X_2\sim\text{Binom}(n_2,\pi_1^2).
$$For simplicity, denote $\pi_1$ by $p$.
The likelihood function $L(p)$ is then
$$
L(p)\propto p^{X_1}(1-p)^{n_1-X_1}\cdot \left(p^2\right)^{X_2}\left(1-p^2\right)^{n_2-X_2}, 
$$
where factors not involving $p$ are dropped by using the $\propto$ notation.
The derivative of $\log(L)$ can be shown as
$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}p} \log\left[L(p)\right] = 
\frac{X_1+2X_2}{p}-\frac{n_1-X_1}{1-p}-\frac{2p(n_2-X_2)}{1-p^2}.
$$
Solving $\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}p} \log\left[L\left(\hat{p}\right)\right] = 0$ leads to
$$
(n_1+2n_2)\hat{p}^2+(n_1-X_1)\hat{p}-(X_1+2X_2)=0,
$$
with solution
$$
\hat{p}=\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}-(n_1-X_1)}{2(n_1+2n_2)},
$$
where
$$
\Delta=(n_1-X_1)^2+4(n_1+2n_2)(X_1+2X_2).
$$One should check the 2nd derivative to confirm maximum but I will skip that here. Numerically, I got $\hat{p}\approx 0.0772$.
Therefore, the expected cell counts are




Boys
Girls
Total




Colorblind
$n_1\hat{p}\approx 698.81$
$n_2\hat{p}^2\approx 54.10$
$752.92$


Normal
$n_1(1-\hat{p})\approx 8350.19$
$n_2(1-\hat{p}^2)\approx 9017.90$
$17368.08$


Total
$9049$
$9072$
$18121$



Then we can use the $G^2$ likelihood ratio formula to get $\Lambda\approx5.119$ with a $p$-value approximately $0.0237$ when calibrated against $\chi_1^2$ distribution. (The degrees of freedom is $1$ because there is one constraint in $H_0$.)

Edit 2: LRT under multinomial model with $1:1$ sex ratio
The purpose of this edit is to demonstrate that the "OBS" in the LRT statistic is not necessarily always the original data counts. This happens when sex ratio is assumed to be $1:1$ but the raw counts are not $1:1$.
If the data from both sexes were collected together rather than separately sampled, we may have a single multinomial model with $3$ free parameters(i.e., $4$ probabilities). The data between boys and girls are negatively dependent in such a model--the more boys we sample, the less girls we see.
If we believe the data come from a population with $1:1$ sex ratio, one more parameter can be removed from the model. If this assumption is correct, then our estimate will be more precise than the corresponding multinomial model without such a sex ratio constraint.
The supposed model is given in the table below, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are two free parameters to be estimated.




Boys
Girls
Total




Colorblind
$Nr_1$
$Nr_2$
$N(r_1+r_2)$


Normal
$N\left(\frac12-r_1\right)$
$N\left(\frac12-r_2\right)$
$N(1-r_1-r_2)$


Total
$\frac{N}{2}$
$\frac{N}{2}$
$N$



Writing down the likelihood and maximizing it leads to MLEs
$$
\hat{r}_1=\frac{X_1}{2N_1},\quad \hat{r}_2=\frac{X_2}{2N_2},
$$
where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are observed number of boys and girls, both being random variables in this model.
The gender-specific colorblind probabilities will be estimated by $2\hat{r}_1$ and $2\hat{r}_2$ and these turn out to be identical to sample proportions. However, the estimated counts are different than those in the 2-independent binomial model (which are just raw data counts):




Boys
Girls
Total




Colorblind
$725.92$
$39.95$
$765.87$


Normal
$8334.58$
$9020.55$
$17355.13$


Total
$9060.5$
$9060.5$
$18121$



Comparing this with the original data table, the fit seems fairly good. Notice that this model makes the estimate total counts of each sex equal, i.e., utilizing the extra information that a sex ratio is $1:1$.
Finally, let's consider the $H_0$ constraint, now given by
$$
H_0: \left(\frac{r_1}{1/2}\right)^2=\frac{r_1}{1/2} \iff 2r_1^2=r_2.
$$
Replacing all $r_2$ by $2r_1^2$, the table form of $H_0$ is:




Boys
Girls
Total




Colorblind
$Nr_1$
$2Nr_1^2$
$Nr_1(1+r_1^2)$


Normal
$N\left(\frac12-r_1\right)$
$N\left(\frac12-2r_1^2\right)$
$N(1-r_1-2r_1^2)$


Total
$\frac{N}{2}$
$\frac{N}{2}$
$N$



Solving this likelihood equation, I got the constrained MLE
$$\hat{r}_1 = \frac{\hat{p}}{2}
$$
where $\hat{p}$ is the estimate from the previous 2-independent binomial model.
The expected count table under $H_0$ is then:




Boys
Girls
Total




Colorblind
$699.70$
$54.03$
$753.74$


Normal
$8360.80$
$9006.46$
$17367.26$


Total
$9060.5$
$9060.5$
$18121$



Comparing this with the expected count table from the 2-independent binomial model, I think they agree to a reasonable degree.
The log likelihood ratio test statistic is trickier. Inside the $\log$, the numerator "OBS" should use counts from the first estimated table; outside the $\log$, the "OBS" factor should use the original raw data table. If this is done, LRT statistic $\Lambda$ will be identical to that from the 2-independent binomial model.
In other words, even though it is unlikely that the data from both sexes were sampled separately, the 2-independent binomial model has essentially treated both sexes on an even ground. This may or may not always be a good choice, depending on the actual ratio of marginal probabilities of scientific interest.
PS: After doing all these, I realized this could be viewed as a reparameterization of the 2-independent binomial model. So there is no practical value here. I'm only hoping that this still has a little educational value in helping us understand what these models do and what the correct way is when computing the LRT statistic.

Let's say i'll use likelihood ratio test, should i then get the probability of:
$$\pi_{girl}=\frac{\text{# Colourblinded girls}}{\text{# Total number of girls}}$$
And the
$$H_0 : \pi_{girl} = \bigg(\frac{\text{# Colourblinded boys}}{\text{# Total number of boys}}\bigg)^2$$
Then calculate the $EXP_j = n\cdot \pi_{girl}$, this is the $H_0$ probability.
Then lastly i'll set up the test:
$$\Lambda_n = 2\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^k OBS_j \log\bigg(\frac{OBS_j}{EXP_j}\bigg)$$
Use the $\chi^2(1)$ to test with.
How does this sound?

Not exactly sure what you meant, but it doesn't look like the usual LRT. You will need to write down the likelihood function first (which is a little bit ambiguous since the problem didn't describe how the data were sampled). Then impose the constraint on unknown parameters in the likelihood and maximize it. That will give the constrained estimate under $H_0$. After that you can then use the $G^2$ formula, replacing all expected counts by the one you obtained.
I'll type it up soon.

That's the obstacle. Like you said, we don't know how data is sampled. So i thought, that maybe if i use the LRT "naive" (that being $\log(\frac{\text{#Colorblind girls}}{\text{# all girls}})$ minus the $\log\bigg(\bigg(\frac{\text{# Colorblind boys}}{\text{# all boys}}\bigg)^2 \bigg)$) then i'll achieve a test statistic of the - again "naive" - probability of girls being colorblind (as given in the table
) and the $H_0$ probability of girls being colorblind.
Then lastly i'll test this $\Lambda_n$ in $\chi^2(1)$ which hopefully could provide me with a p-value i can conclude something with.

I just edited with a simple independent binomial model, which has minimal assumptions made. If you want to use yours, it's better to state explicitly what model can give rise to your estimate.

The independent assumption between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is acceptable. But i have not seen the assumption that $X_i$ for $i = {1,2,3,...,n}$ such be Binominal distributed.
Yet again, i thank you for your time and feedback.

It's doomed to be Binomial, if we believe (1) that subjects are independent (i.e., no siblings or close relatives), (1) that subjects come from a common population (i.e., good sampling represents the population well), and (1) that we condition on the total number of subjects. If these assumptions are reasonable, each subject gives a Bernoulli outcome and the data counts are just sum of i.i.d. Bernoulli variables, namely, a Binomial variable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
